# i want to delete old deployment and service from the pipeline code on jenkins

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

when i commit a change on github the build triggered, but after i see no changes on my spring boot app, i think is due to unchanged pods.

so i want to delete the old deployment and service before the deployment stage on jenkins pipeline

i tried this code but didnt work

```
stage('Delete Existing Deployment') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "kubectl delete deployment ${deploymentName}"
                }
            }
        }
        
stage('Delete Existing Service') {
       steps {
            script {
               sh "kubectl delete service ${serviceName}"
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way kubectl works, if a new deployment is applied, the old deployment and service should automatically get replaced without you having to manually remove them beforehand. To verify this, perform the deployment and run:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

with the appropriate namespace if you are deploying into anything other than the default namespace. You should see a column called age which shows how old the pod is. If it is recent, then it means that your deployment went through correctly. If not, it means there is something wrong with either the command you use to do the deployment or your kubeconfig.

It could also mean that Kubernetes didn't detect any changes between the current deployment and the new one, and therefore chose not to deploy anything. If this is the case, it might be a problem in your build. Perhaps it is checking the wrong branch? Or perhaps the webhook you are using to trigger your build isn't working properly?

The fact that running `kubectl delete` doesn't delete the deployment points to a problem with your kubeconfig, where your kubeconfig likely isn't pointing to the correct cluster (or is missing entirely). Note that when you run Jenkins, it runs with its own Jenkins user, so go into the machine that hosts your Jenkins instance and run:

```
su - jenkins
```

To get you into the Jenkins user. Afterwards, run:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

And ensure that you are pointed to the correct cluster.

If all this looks fine, run the commands and pay attention to any error or warning that may lead you to the final solution.